# Update Random Number in css href

Tags: html, css, caching, href

I am having a css link tag in my html like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skin.css">
```

I want to add a random number saved in local storage to href like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="skin.css?cb=sessionStorage.cbVersion">
```

I know that we can assign an id to this and later change the href attribute value but I am trying to find is there any way to implement the same thing without writing any extra logic.

Comment: get those random numbers and play with some javascript like this `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'skin.css?cb=sessionStorage.' + randomFileNumber + '.css'>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is static. As in: it will always parse the value of an `href` attribute as a string. So, given the above, it will try to access `{your-domain}/skin.css?cb=sessionStorage.cbVersion`.

If you need it to be variable, you have two options:

- use whatever logic you need at the time you're creating the HTML of your page on server side using the language you use on server side (php, Java, etc...)
- use JavaScript on client side (when the page was loaded in the browser).

In the second case, you don't have to use an `id`, although it's a common (and recommended) method for targeting elements. But you need a way in which to uniquely identify your element so you can change its `href`.

Simple example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" data-href="dynamic-stylesheet">
<script>
  const link = document.querySelector('link[data-href="dynamic-stylesheet"]');
  link.href = `skin.css?cb=${sessionStorage.cbVersion || 'defaultValue'}`;
</script>
```

Note this won't work on StackOverflow as snippets are sandboxed and not allowed to access `sessionStorage`.

Also note I removed the `href` altogether as, if present and invalid, it will result in a `404` error, as it will be parsed at the moment the `<link>` is parsed, which has to be before you run your script. Or, as an alternative, you could not have the `<link>` at all and create it using JavaScript, with the desired `href` value.

Last, but not least, you should always provide a defaultValue for when `cbVersion` is not found on `sessionStorage`. An improved version of the above script would use a try/catch for retrieving the sessionStorage value and provide the `defaultValue` if the resulting value is still falsy:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" data-href="dynamic-stylesheet">
<script>
  const link = document.querySelector('link[data-href="dynamic-stylesheet"]');
  let cbVersion;
  try {
    cbVersion = sessionStorage.cbVersion;
  } catch(err) { 
    //console.log(err)
  }
  link.href = `skin.css?cb=${cbVersion || 'defaultValue'}`;
</script>
```

As you can see, the above tries to load `https://stacksnippets.net/skin.css?cb=defaultValue` (which doesn't exist), and does not output an error about not being able to access `sessionStorage` on SO.